# Create a Polars Dataframe by appending multiple row at a time

Tags: python, python-polars

**How can I make DataFrame and then more rows one at a time?**

```
import polars as pl


df_polars = pl.DataFrame({
    'abc': [],
    'def': [],
    'ghi': []
})


value_to_set = 10.0
df_polars = df_polars.extend([
    pl.lit(None).alias('abc'),   
    pl.lit(value_to_set).alias('def'),
    pl.lit(None).alias('ghi')  
])


print(df_polars)
```

It only works for one field at a time. What is a more efficient approach to add several rows to my data-frame?

Answer (score 4):

Brainstorming idea => adding a list of the dictionary, converting to DF, and concatenating:

```
new_rows = [{'abc': None, 'def': value, 'ghi': None} for value in values_to_set]  # list of the dictionary
new_df = pl.DataFrame(new_rows)                             # new DataFrame with the new rows
df_polars = pl.concat([df_polars, new_df])                  # Concatenate
```

Comment: You can use concat or vstack. The difference is that concat will rechunk whereas vstack won't. The implication of that is concat will be slower for each insert but will leave the df in a single chunk. The single chunk is better for reads. vstack will be faster for the insert but then subsequent reads will be slower. I think most of the time it's better to concat but it's good to know about vstack too.